# Is it possible to save my progress online in Candy Box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

In Candy Box, the only way to save was to have a five character automatically generated password which would overwrite the server's save with a new one every time you saved. Is there a way to do this is Candy Box 2?

An example of why one would want to do is is if they cannot copy the save text and need to access the save on a different computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.** Save data is stored locally in your browser cache, and can only be transferred to another computer using the "export save" function. It is not stored online anywhere.

Comment: Aww. Makes it annoying to export then..

Comment: @JeffreyLin Yep. Though this was likely done to keep their servers from totally overloading.

Comment: @JeffreyLin As in, nobody can load up a random url and throw all the candies associated with that URL on the ground? That is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately you cannot save to the server but you can transfer your saves to different machines.

You need to save the text by clicking this button

[image: Save]

You can then load it on *any* machine by pasting the text in the box below.

[image: Load]

Answer (score 0):

Click/tap the button that says "Save on slot 1". This button will save all of your current progress.

Then, scroll down and you will see this link:

https://candybox2.github.io/?slot=1

Click/tap on the link and it will send you to Candy Box 2, with all of your progress saved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes when you get 30 candies a box will show up to “ask the dev for more features” it will cost 30 candies at first then 5 candies for the next ones. Keep buying until you see the save icon. Click it then select the file you want the save your game on, then click save. When you want to load your game again Scroll down and click on the link to the save file. This will work when you have logged out and the game reset, so don’t stress out! Cheers!!